# How do I check if an array includes an object with the same field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

What is the **best** method to handle this?
consider i'm handling a sign-up list database and i want to know whether a user the same username already exists or not?

something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < database.user.length; ++i) {
    if( database.user[i].username === username ) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

is there something better??

PS1: database.user is an array of objects

PS2: and I already know about the [Array->indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) func and it didn't help.

Comment: that is a nice approach

Comment: Yours seems fine, and is probably the fastest. However, most databases have a way to check if something "exists" without getting the result, if that's an option.

Comment: Using an actual database would probably be better.

Comment: You can also use Array's [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method

Comment: what is `database` in your code?

Comment: its good what you have already done, rest are opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code goes all the way the whole array even if an item at index 0 matches your query. You could use `Array.prototype.some` but even that one will fall short in performance compared to `Array.prototype.findIndex`. So my advice would be using findIndex.

```
database.user.findIndex(e => e.username === username) === -1 && login(username);
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, any *other* way of doing this is just hiding the fact that, under the hood, they are just doing exactly what your code already does.

For example, you could filter your array, and check whether it's length is `>=` 1

```
var userExists = database.user.filter(u => u.username === username).length >= 1;
```

It's shorter, and arguably a little more readable than your original, but its not necessarily best, and neither is it likely to be faster.

Slightly better would be to use `find` - as this returns as soon as an element matches, meaning the whole array is not evaluated

```
var userExists = database.user.find(u => u.username === username) !== undefined;
```

(`some` would also be appropriate)

---

Note, this answer uses ES6 format for lambda expressions, the equivalent in unsupporting browsers would be

```
var userExists = database.user.filter(function(u) {return  u.username == username;}).length >= 1
// or
var userExists = database.user.find(function(u) {return  u.username == username;}) !== undefined;
```

Comment: The OP just need to test if any element pass the condition. So [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is more appropriate. `filter` will test **each** element.

Comment: The OP doesn't need return the found value, he **already have** it (the searching `username`). So `find` does redundant work. Furthermore it require ES6.

Comment: @hindmost now I have no idea what you're talking about! My point was only that instead of a `for` loop, there are any number of ways to do the **same thing**. Furthermore my answer *already says what you just said about ES6* and provides an alternative! Did you have a point?